# WordPress - posted_on not displaying (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, sticky

I have been working on a WP theme (based on twentyeleven) for a while that has a spotlight (featured) area for sticky posts: http://www.designated.net.au/testbed/wordpress/

The problem I am having is that the posted_on declaration does not display for the sticky post.  I am a total noob when it comes to PHP so I don't really know what I'm doing.

To feature the sticky posts I used this guide: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-featured-post-layout-in-wordpress

But I changed the display of the post to use the code from content.php.  So I am using the following:

```
<?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
<div class="entry-meta">
<?php twentyeleven_posted_on(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-meta -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

That is the part that doesn't display.

I'm happy to supply more code if you need me to.

Comment: How about your global variable `$post`? `var_dump($post)` befor the if statement. And then, check the value of `$the_post->post_type`

Comment: How do I implement that and check the value?

Comment: This is what I get: `object(stdClass)#215 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(15) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2012-09-11 04:23:42" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2012-09-11 04:23:42" ["post_content"]=> string(187) "`.

Comment: The funny thing is that it's all there in the source of the page.  It just doesn't display in any of my browsers.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it.  It seems I stuffed up when I copied the article div at the top of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was a problem with the CSS.  For some reason it was set to absolute with zero left and top.

Comment: Actually that was only for singular posts.  It is still missing on the main page.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. It seems I stuffed up when I copied the article div at the top of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display the post date, use `<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>`

You can display the date in any format. Check this Codex for [Formatting Date and Time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `get_post_type( $post->ID )`.