# posted_on not displaying wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

[I also seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380813/wordpress-posted-on-not-displaying-php) and it didn't help me.

Notes doesn't display and all the page above the title seems to die (it has no footer). I have tried also `var_dump($post)`,

result:

```
object(WP_Post)#6474 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(1096) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-10-17 23:01:15" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-10-17 20:01:15" ["post_content"]=> string(3) "123" ["post_title"]=> string(54) "Цветочная феерия для свадьбы." ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(31) "flower-for-wedding-extravaganza" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-10-27 14:47:49" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-10-27 11:47:49" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(31) "http://eventprestige.ru/?p=1096" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }
```

and also tried `echo get_the_date()` and have seen nothing.

Pages, not notes, display correctly.

What's the problem?

Comment: post_content is correct

Comment: `post_date` isn't what you need?

Comment: no, i found that i need to declare function at content.php from template-tags.php, and post will shown, the last problem is to include footer